# Highlight on ListView Scroll Issue

Tags: android, listview, highlight

I have a strange problem with a Listview and the selected item.
All works fine until i select an item, and i scroll the list.
If i scroll fast and the selected item is not visible anymore, the background color of the selected item stay visible during the scroll, even between two rows.
This is my listview XML:

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollingCache="false" />
```

This is my adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImpiantiCercatiViewHolder icvh;


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ricerca_impianti_list_adapter, null);
        icvh = new ImpiantiCercatiViewHolder();
        icvh.sigla = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txv_impiantiSigla);
        icvh.tipo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txv_impianti_tipo);
        icvh.denDitta = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txv_impianti_denominazione_ditta);
        icvh.indDitta = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txv_impianti_indirizzo_ditta);
        icvh.dataScad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txv_impianti_data_scadenza);
        convertView.setTag(icvh);
    } else {
        icvh = (ImpiantiCercatiViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Impianto i = impianti.get(position);
    if (i != null) {
        icvh.tipo.setText(VimpUtils.ritornaSiglaTipoImpianto(i.getTipoImpianto()));
        icvh.sigla.setText(i.getSigla() + "-" + i.getNumero() + "-" + i.getAnno());
        icvh.denDitta.setText(i.getDenominazioneDitta());
        icvh.indDitta.setText(i.getIndirizzoDitta() + " - " + i.getComuneDitta());
        icvh.dataScad.setText(df.format(i.getDataScadenzaVerifica()));
    }
    return convertView;
}   

static class ImpiantiCercatiVi`enter code here`ewHolder {
    TextView sigla;
    TextView tipo;
    TextView denDitta;
    TextView indDitta;
    TextView dataScad;
}
```

and this is my adapter xml:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_lista_impianto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_impianto_dark" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txv_impiantiSigla"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:textAppearance="@style/bigTextBlack" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txv_impianti_tipo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/bigTextBlack" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txv_impianti_data_scadenza"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:textAppearance="@style/bigText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txv_impianti_denominazione_ditta"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:textAppearance="@style/bigText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txv_impianti_indirizzo_ditta"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textAppearance="@style/bigText" />
```

EDIT:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkeMu.png) there is the screen with the problem.

Comment: can you pls post the screenshot of your problem

Comment: Done =) http://i.stack.imgur.com/xkeMu.png

Answer (score 0):

```
View selectedview;
int selectedposition
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImpiantiCercatiViewHolder icvh;



        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ricerca_impianti_list_adapter, null);
        icvh = new ImpiantiCercatiViewHolder();
        icvh.sigla = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txv_impiantiSigla);
        icvh.tipo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txv_impianti_tipo);
        icvh.denDitta = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txv_impianti_denominazione_ditta);
        icvh.indDitta = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txv_impianti_indirizzo_ditta);
        icvh.dataScad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txv_impianti_data_scadenza);
        convertView.setTag(icvh);

    Impianto i = impianti.get(position);
    if (i != null) {
        icvh.tipo.setText(VimpUtils.ritornaSiglaTipoImpianto(i.getTipoImpianto()));
        icvh.sigla.setText(i.getSigla() + "-" + i.getNumero() + "-" + i.getAnno());
        icvh.denDitta.setText(i.getDenominazioneDitta());
        icvh.indDitta.setText(i.getIndirizzoDitta() + " - " + i.getComuneDitta());
        icvh.dataScad.setText(df.format(i.getDataScadenzaVerifica()));
    }
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                if(selectedposition == position){
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    selectedview = convertView;
                }

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       if (selectedview != null && selectedview != view && selectedposition != position)
     {

    selectedview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

     selectedview = view;

    selectedposition = position;

    selectedview.setBackgroundColor(color); //highlighted color

        }
    });

     return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please write some introduction as to what this code does, not just post a block of code?

Comment: it will highlight selected item. even if you scroll the listview selected item still have bckgroud.